# SqlServer: iterative query script with variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query script (check if a certain value exists in a table, if yes delete that row), which I need run with different values.

Instead of duplicate the script several times and replace the value, I want to make it simple.

Can I do as it in a iterative fashion, each time with different value, the values will be predefined?

Thanks.

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tId = '10')
    EXEC('UPDATE table2 SET type=N''user'' WHERE id = 10') 
[ ELSE
    DELETE FROM tabl2 WHERE id = 10
]
```

The value 10 here, I want to treat it as variable, so that I that iterate this query with different predefined value

Comment: Why make it iterative? That implies you doing RBAR which is going to be a lot slower. Why not just delete them all at once? Delete From SomeTable where YourKey IN (KeyValue1, KeyValue2, etc)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're trying to set `tabl2.type` to *user* where the ID exists in `table1`, and delete the record otherwise.

Like Sean Lange said, don't make it iterative, try something like this instead:

```
--update the records in table2 that have a record in table1
update  table2
set     type='user'
where   id in (
    select  tID
    from    table1
    where   tID in (10,11,12...n)
    )

--delete the records in table2 that lack a record in table1
delete  table2
where   id not in (
    select  tID
    from    table1
    where   tID in (10,11,12...n)
    )
```

As much as you can, you want to avoid doing things RBAR (row by agonizing row) and instead take advantage of sets of records.